# jointjs link renders like a filled open poly

Tags: jointjs, rappid

I've copied the hello world example into a VueJS app, things work as expected.

I then changed added:

```
        router: { name: 'manhattan' },
```

to the link constructor. when I move the nodes around I get the link rendering as in the attached screen shot.

Has anyone else ever encountered this and have a fix?

mc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

most likely you've forgotten to include the `join.css` stylesheet